# How do I choose a model/estimator?

Tags: machine-learning

I've learned many different types of ways to find models with regression,  and many different model to find clusters with clustering algorithms however ever since I started with ML, I've always wondered how would one choose to use one algorithm over another? Should we always measure the errors of each model then make our selection based on that?

I've learned things like SVM, Perceptron algorithm, Feed forward Neural Networks, Boltzmann Machines however when should I choose one over the other? This has always really confused me.

So from what I understand, a data scientist would just,

```
for i in all_algorithms:
    use_algorithm(data)
use_best_algorithm(data)
```

Side Idea: I was also reading that the algorithm doesn't really matter but it is the amount of data that you have which really matters.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems in your question can be divided into two types:

1. Unsupervised learning: class labels are unknown

   Example algorithms include k-means, k-nearest-neighbour, mixture model, hierarchical clustering, etc.
2. Supervised learning: class labels are known for at least a subset of the cases, and the algorithm is expected to generalize patterns it learned in the training data instead to predict classes or perform regression on new cases.

   Classification algorithms include SVM, neural nets (logstic, softmax), etc.
   Regression algorithms include neural nets (with real-valued outputs), linear regression, nonlinear regression etc.

For unsupervised clustering specifically, there is no gold-standard measure of performance. (There is, however, a large number of measures that examine properties such as between-cluster distance, within-cluster distance, stability, association with domain-specific variables.)
Therefore, practitioners may try a few algorithms and present the consensus clusters (i.e. consensus clustering), or they may choose the one that reveals 'interesting' patterns that are worthy of further investigation.

For supervised classification/regressions, it is well known that given a sufficiently large amount of data, all the algorithms may perform similarly, provided that each is properly parameterized and tuned.

Where the algorithms differ is in how fast they converge to the optimum accuracy (e.g. sensitivity, specificity, precision, recall). Given that data is often limiting, it may be worthwhile to identify the algorithm with superior performance using your limited data.

Sometimes, your data may even be so limiting that all the algorithms you try have poor accuracy, suggesting that information contained in data is insufficient for accurate classification/regression (e.g. predicting long-term stock market prices using the price history).

In order to test the performance of the algorithm properly, you need to set up cross-validation correctly so that your results are not confounded by algorithms fitting spurious noise in the training data (i.e. overfitting).

You might find Andrew Ng's free online course helpful: http://www.ml-class.org

Comment: If we are given a million data points of a quadratic function and we use a linear regression model on it. Then that would not work, would it?

Comment: If the quadratic function is both increasing and decreasing in the domain of the data points, then the linear regression will miss the association between $x$ and $y$. (It would report a slope close to 0.) Although some die-hard statisticians discourage it, it is often useful to plot out the data before your analysis, if possible (i.e. exploratory analysis). If the data is highly multidimensional, you may wish to consider using mutual information to first determine whether there is any association between the response and the predictor variables.

Comment: On the contrary, we typically try to use the simplest model to explain the data, in order to avoid overfitting. If you are choosing between models of varying complexity, you would consider using AIC or BIC to choose the model that maximizes likelikhood without using too many parameters.